# How can I order a facet by the slope generated in a plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I order a facet by the slope generated in a plot using ggplot2? My impression is that `after_stat(slope)` should do the job but it has seemingly no effect as the screenshot below shows the negative slope is clearly not the last plot in the faceting.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100

data_filtered <- data.frame(
  start_date = rep(seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "days", length.out = n), each = 5),
  value = rnorm(n * 5, mean = 10, sd = 3),
  id = rep(letters[1:5], each = n)
)

data_filtered$slope <- ifelse(data_filtered$id == "a", 0.5, -0.5)
data_filtered$value <- data_filtered$value + data_filtered$slope * as.numeric(data_filtered$start_date) / 100
slope <- coef(lm(value ~ as.numeric(start_date), data = data_filtered))[2]

data_filtered %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = start_date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~fct_reorder(id, after_stat(slope), .desc = TRUE), scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside", 
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))
```

I should mention, I also tried calculating the slope separately and using `fct_reorder` to reorder but had no success.

```
fct_reorder(data_filtered, factor(id), slope, na.rm = TRUE, .desc = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the help for `stat_smooth()`, `slope` doesn't appear to be something that can be obtained with `after_stat()`.  However, you should be able to do it by calculating the slope first and then reordering the factor.  It worked for me here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
n <- 100

data_filtered <- data.frame(
  start_date = rep(seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "days", length.out = n), each = 5),
  value = rnorm(n * 5, mean = 10, sd = 3),
  id = rep(letters[1:5], each = n)
)

data_filtered$slope <- ifelse(data_filtered$id == "a", 0.5, -0.5)
data_filtered$value <- data_filtered$value + data_filtered$slope * 
as.numeric(data_filtered$start_date) / 100
```

```r
data_filtered %>% 
  mutate(b = coef(lm(value ~ start_date))[2], .by = id) %>%
  mutate(id = as.factor(id), 
         id = reorder(id, b, mean, decreasing = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = start_date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside", 
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>